# git-remote-hg use "--insecure" in git clone hg::someurl

Tags: git, mercurial, https

I use git for vcs, and I started working with a group that uses mercurial. Therefore I've been checking out [**git-remote-hg**](https://github.com/dubiousjim/yagh) as a bridge.

However, the **hg** repos are behind https, with a self-signed certificate. The simplest way to get around this with just **hg** is to add the "--insecure" option during the clone.

```
hg clone --insecure hgRepoURL
```

I cannot see how to add this option for the **git** clone command

```
git clone --insecure hg::hgRepoURL
```

Does not work. Looking for suggestions or other ways to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bridge you're using does not pass on any parameters to `hg clone`. As a temporary workaround you can change [this line](https://github.com/dubiousjim/yagh/blob/master/src/remote-hg.py#L254) to `self._do("hg", "clone", "--insecure", self.hg_url, hg_repo_dir)`.